# Laziest way to populate Enum from spreadsheet C#

Tags: c#, csv, enums

I'm making a game in unity that predominantly revolves around crafting. Items are just enum values. I made it so that it loads all recipes from a CSV file at runtime. I was hoping to make it so that the game can be developed mostly just by updating the CSV file and by adding appropriately named image files to the images folder because that is super convenient and the spreadsheet is easy on my eyes.

I'd prefer it if I did not have to manually copy/paste values from the spreadsheet into my Enum definition each time I export a CSV file from my spreadsheet.

Keep in mind that the Enum needs to be at least partially hardcoded because there are at least some hardcoded references to specific Enum Values.

Someone mentioned compile time code, but I never actually compile in visual studio because it is a Unity Project and in fact, the way the project is set up, if I accidently compile from visual studio, the unity project breaks for some reason until I delete all the compiled files.

**What would be the best way to proceed?**

Comment: I was thinking maybe just make an external executable that writes a .cs file containing the enum. Or maybe a script that runs when unity compiles that over writes a .CS file.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the problem from a wrong direction. Using an `enum` to define the items is not the best way.

I wouldn't recommend to use a csv file to store the recipe. As it would be difficult manage recipe that compose multiple materials. However, it can still be done, by [normalizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) the data.

Ideally your data structure should looks like this :

```
public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Recipe
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}
public class Material
{
    public int ItemID { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

And, you can populate them through a format that support hierarchy like XML, Json, etc :

```
<Items>
<Item ID="1">Paper</Item>
<Item ID="2">Ink</Item>
<Item ID="3">Book</Item>
</Items>

<Recipes>
<Recipe>
    <ProductID>3</ProductID>
    <Materials>
    <Material ItemID="1" Count="100" />
    <Material ItemID="2" Count="5" />
    </Materials>
</Recipe>
</Recipes>
```

Comment: Typing out XML completely defeats the purpose. If I was going to do that, I may as well just type out the actual c# code. The point of a spreadsheet is that you merely fill out cells and do not need to look at all the source code in-between the values, and it keeps things together in a 2-dimensional grid instead of a sprawling list of nested objects. Furthermore, your XML example is not human readable since it refers to items by number.

Comment: Like I said, you can always flatten out the hierarchical data by normalizing them. The ID doesn't have to be a number, you can substitute with item name. It is merely for illustration.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom [AssetImporter](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetImporter.html) in Unity.

Which basically means that you would add an editor extension to your project that will process any CSV file in the entire project. Unity controls when your importer runs.

Here is a quick one I made for you. You would spin over the contents of the csv file and simply generate a big string representing the file you want to create and then just `File.WriteAllText` to generate the output.

```csharp
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Testing : AssetPostprocessor
{
    static string extension = ".csv";        // Our custom extension
    static string newExtension = ".cs";        // Extension of newly created asset - it MUST be ".asset", nothing else is allowed...

    public static bool HasExtension(string asset)
    {
        return asset.EndsWith(extension, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public static string ConvertToInternalPath(string asset)
    {
        string left = asset.Substring(0, asset.Length - extension.Length);
        return left + newExtension;
    }

    // This is called always when importing something
    static void OnPostprocessAllAssets(
        string[] importedAssets,
        string[] deletedAssets,
        string[] movedAssets,
        string[] movedFromAssetPaths)
    {
        foreach (string asset in importedAssets)
        {
            // This is our detection of file - by extension
            if (HasExtension(asset))
            {
                ImportMyAsset(asset);
            }
        }
    }

    // Imports my asset from the file
    static void ImportMyAsset(string asset)
    {
        // Path to out new asset
        string newPath = ConvertToInternalPath(asset);

        File.WriteAllText(newPath, "// works!");
    }
}
```

Comment: So your code example will create a .cs file for each .csv file that exists anywhere inside the unity project folder immediately before unity compiles the code?

Comment: Yeah, or theoretically you could roll them all up into a single .cs file, but that is what its doing.

Comment: I probably just need to run a script once before compiling since I am just trying to create one CS file. How do you do that?

Comment: Sure you could do the same thing with a script that you run from the command line also. There are a lot of options for that. Using something like nodejs or python might be best. The above answer is purely for how to do it during unity builds.